# How can I force Voiceover (MacOS) to read out a dollar amount correctly, ignoring inner span elements?

Tags: html, user-interface, accessibility, voiceover, screen-readers

I have this content (simplified):

```html
<div>
  $<span class="enlarged-text">245</span>.50
</div>
```

And when I use `CAPSLOCK + Right` (read next element) with Voiceover on Safari (MacOS Monterey 12.7.1) it reads it out as *"two hundred and forty five dollars and fifty cents"*, **as desired**.

However, using the auto-readout feature of voiceover - initiated using `CAPSLOCK + A` - voiceover quite bizarrely reads out *"two dollars, forty five point five zero"*. Is there a way to fix this?

I've tried the undocumented `role="text"` on the surrounding div and it helps somewhat, but instead reads out as *"two hundred and forty five dollars, fifty"* using the auto-readout. And using `CAPSLOCK + Right` it reads as *"two hundred and forty five dollars point five zero"*.

```html
<div role="text">
  $<span class="enlarged-text">245</span>.50
</div>
```

I also tried surrounding each piece in a separate `span`, but it made no difference:

```html
<div role="text">
  <span>$</span><span class="enlarged-text">245</span><span>.50</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the CSS for enlarged-text and/or which styles are applied to the parent div and the span ? You may find it strange, but sometimes VoiceOver is influenced by apparently innocent unrelated CSS. Thank you.

Comment: That's bizarre! Unfortunately, I was able to reproduce the issue with just the HTML shown above, so I suspect that's not the issue.

Comment: OK. Too bad. Another question: have you tried with the latest MacOS ? And on iOS ? Just to find out if  it's VoiceOver in general, or only on Mac. I wouldn't be surprised if it worked fine on iOS, as there are much more bizarre bugs on MacOS than iOS.

Comment: Thanks @QuentinC. Yeah that's a fair question, I haven't gotten to iOS yet, no. Will see. The bit about versions of macos is a good one, someone in my team tried testing on their non-updated device and got an even worse result as I recall  Thanks for debugging with me though. I agree, I might just have to find a compromise and settle for something halfway decent, since it seems like voiceover on Mac is ultimately a bit flawed in some areas.

Comment: I'm out of ideas, so probably, the best you can do if you want to do something is to use the visually hidden pattern as given in VonC's answer. It's actually sad that you need to do that, as your HTML has really nothing special. Or you can just do nothing and consider that, anyway, such screen reader quirks are common, blind users are quite well used to them, and will still understand.

Comment: This is the kind of case where we may hit the limit: is it really good to optimize accessibility for a specific context, with the risk to degrade accessibility in other contexts ? Sometimes it's preferable to do nothing. It's maybe better to be 80% everywhere rather than 100% in one case and 50% for all the others, if you understand what I mean. TL,DR, don't forget to test everywhere that your fix won't break anything with other devices/browsers/screen readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are experiencing inconsistent behavior with Voiceover's automatic readout feature, try and Use the `aria-label` attribute to explicitly specify the text that should be read out by Voiceover ([ARIA](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA): Accessible Rich Internet Applications).

```html
<div aria-label="245 dollars and 50 cents">
  $<span class="enlarged-text">245</span>.50
</div>
```

You can also use the [`aria-hidden` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-hidden) to hide the elements that are causing incorrect readouts from the screen reader, and add a visually hidden `span` that contains the correct format for the screen reader.

```html
<div>
  <span aria-hidden="true">$<span class="enlarged-text">245</span>.50</span>
  <span class="visually-hidden">245 dollars and 50 cents</span>
</div>
```

`.visually-hidden` is a class that hides the content visually but keeps it accessible to screen readers.
It would be defined as:

```css
.visually-hidden {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: 0;
}
```

(From "[CSS in Action / Invisible Content Just for Screen Reader Users](https://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/)")

You might also try using the `content` CSS property with the [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) or [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) pseudo-elements to inject the currency symbol, which may not interfere with Voiceover's readout logic.

```html
<div class="price">
  <span class="enlarged-text">245</span>.50
</div>
```

```css
.price::before {
  content: "$";
}
```

---

As noted by [QuentinC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1971216/quentinc) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77420747/how-can-i-force-voiceover-macos-to-read-out-a-dollar-amount-correctly-ignorin/77429622#comment136510016_77429622):

> Attributes `aria-label` and `aria-labelledby` only work on interactive/focusable elements and landmarks, or elements having such roles. So, in this case it won't work.

Actually, `aria-label` can sometimes be used on non-interactive elements to provide an accessible name, but its support can indeed be inconsistent across different screen readers and scenarios.

The goal remains to make sure the screen reader correctly interprets the dollar amount as a whole number followed by the cents, without being misled by the HTML structure.

You could try and combine the dollar sign and the number in a single `span` without visual space, and then use CSS to visually enlarge only the dollar amount part.

```html
<div>
  <span aria-hidden="true" class="price">$245<span class="cents">.50</span></span>
  <span class="visually-hidden">245 dollars and 50 cents</span>
</div>
```

```css
.price .cents {
  font-size: smaller;
}
```

Alternatively, if modifying the visual appearance is not an option, you could use JavaScript to dynamically set the `aria-label` attribute based on the content of the spans when the page loads or when the content changes.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var priceDiv = document.querySelector('.price-container');
  var price = priceDiv.innerText;
  priceDiv.setAttribute('aria-label', price.replace('$', '') + ' dollars and ' + price.split('.')[1] + ' cents');
};
```

```html
<div class="price-container" role="text">
  $<span class="enlarged-text">245</span>.50
</div>
```

The JavaScript approach manipulates the `aria-label` dynamically, making sure the label is always set to the correct dollar amount that needs to be read out.

If none of the above solutions work due to the specific quirks of Voiceover, check, as QuentinC suggests, if any existing CSS rules are interfering with the screen reader's ability to correctly interpret the content.

---

> It is just a shame, I'd prefer to have the one element that is read by both visual and screen reader users. Otherwise, it is easy for content to get out of sync.

To mitigate the risk of content getting out of sync, you could use JavaScript to dynamically update the visually hidden text based on the visible content.
That way, any changes to the visible price would automatically be reflected in the screen reader text.

Use a visually hidden span in addition to the visible content.

```html
<div id="price-container">
    $<span class="enlarged-text">245</span>.50
    <span class="visually-hidden" id="accessible-price"></span>
</div>
```

Make sure it is accessible to screen readers but not visible.

```css
.visually-hidden {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: 0;
}
```

Dynamically set the content of the visually hidden span.

```js
function updateAccessiblePrice() {
    var priceText = document.getElementById('price-container').innerText;
    var accessiblePrice = priceText.replace('$', '') + ' dollars and ' + priceText.split('.')[1] + ' cents';
    document.getElementById('accessible-price').innerText = accessiblePrice;
}

// Initial update
updateAccessiblePrice();

// Update when the content changes (e.g., via AJAX, user action, etc.)
// That needs to be triggered appropriately depending on how your content updates
```

That approach would make sure the screen reader text is always in sync with the visible text.

It requires a bit of extra effort to set up, but it effectively addresses the concern of maintaining consistency between what is read by screen readers and what is seen by sighted users.

Comment: Attributes aria-label and aria-labelledby only work on interactive/focusable elements and landmarks, or elements having such roles. So, in this case it won't work.

Comment: @QuentinC Good point, thank you for your feedback. I have included your comment for more visibility, and proposed some alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @VonC, if no-one knows of a simple way to do this better then I suspect I'll have to go with the visually hidden second span you mention at the start there. It's just a shame, I'd prefer to have the one element that's read by both visual and screen reader users. Otherwise it's easy for content yo get out of sync.

Comment: @CharlieTaylor OK. I have edited the answer to include a dynamic update approach, which could be of interest here.

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript you could make it a bit dynamically but not perfect at all

```
window.onload = function() {
  var priceDiv = document.querySelector('.price-container');
  var price = priceDiv.innerText;
  priceDiv.setAttribute('aria-label', price.replace('$', '') + ' dollars and ' + price.split('.')[1] + ' cents');
};
```